# Deleting string through menu

Tags: java, menu, int

I have a programme in which i use the scanner.
i have different options but can't figure out how to let 'the user' delete something from the array. I've decided to start with

```
   private static void DeleteTrack(){
   System.out.println("Enter Track Number to Delete: ");
   int tracnum =in.nextInt();
```

Now I can't decide how to go about the rest of it. 
I managed to add tracks to array and to show them up in the menu, now i need to allow 'the user' to enter the id of the track so it deletes from the array. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For a 2-D array...

```
//...//

arrayType[] tempArray = new arrayType[arrayName.length - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++)
{
    if (i < tracnum)
        tempArray[i] = arrayName[i];
    else if (i > tracnum)
        tempArray[i - 1] = arrayName[i];
    // Does all except arrayName[tracnum]
}
arrayName = new arrayType[tempArray.length];

// Put back in array
for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.length; i++
    arrayName[i] = tempArray[i];

//...//
```

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid, do i just copy and paste it and change the names of arrays ?

Comment: Yes, replace arrayType with what type your array is and arrayName with your array. You can leave tempArray as-is.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the very first line, think i don;t know what to put in array type. My array name is mp3Player, i've replaced all arrayName with it and it looks fine just the type now.

Comment: Is it `String[]` `int[]` `boolean[]` etc.etc.